# Does anyone know if the syntax for a ruby .gemspec file using ">=" is valid for these three entries?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In ruby, the entries for a .gemspec file are as follows:

```
s.required_ruby_version     = '>= 2.3.1'
s.required_rubygems_version = '>= 2.6.4'
s.rubygems_version          = '>= 2.6.4'
```

I always used the first variant.

```
s.required_ruby_version     = '>= 2.3.1'
```

Lately, I had received some error with the other 
two when I was using this:

```
s.required_rubygems_version = '2.6.4'
```

I tried to install my own gem and ran into
this weird problem, which confused me. So I
assumed that others would also run into this
problem - rubygems insisted on using a 
different gem version, which was odd to me.
(I always use the latest version these days
myself.)

But this seemed too stringent compared to >=.

Does anyone of you happen to know if >= is valid
for all three mentioned fields?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual error message you're seeing.